# How can a user skip a step in Journey Builder?

Tags: journeybuilder

There are some steps that may need to be skipped during a journey.  For example, if one of our users talks to a person on the phone they may decide to skip the step of mailing/emailing an artifact because it was covered during the phone call.  How can a user skip a step instead of having to send the mail/email in the journey to progress the journey?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

If you have an attribute in your data extension that captures that a subscriber has talked over phone, then this attribute can be added to a decision split and only those subscribers who have not contacted can be sent mail.

The remaining path can be made to join the same journey path after the email send activity so that you can skip Email send.